# Android Studio 2.1.2 Extreme Typing Lag on Mac

Tags: android, android-studio

Finally bit the bullet and moved from Eclipse to Android Studio. I'm running this on a late 2012 mac mini i7 with 8 gb ram. It is unbearably slow and lags every time I try to type something.

Currently I'm using the following

-Xms512m
-Xmx2048m
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=256m
-XX:+UseCompressedOops

I've tried the suggestions in this post [How to speed up Android Studio on a Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28784387/how-to-speed-up-android-studio-on-a-mac)

Any secret settings I'm missing?

Comment: Does the same happen with a plain Intellij installation?

Comment: Not trying to edit md (Markdown) files? Got unbearably slow response on AS in windows so  got a standalone MD editor.

Comment: are you working on a new project or an old/big one

Comment: @cricket_007 just installed regular intelij and no that runs great

Comment: @MounirElfassi it was a legacy project imported from eclipse - so yes old, not sure how big is big but there's a deff a code base there

Comment: @MikeT no markdown just java

Comment: Okay, great, you aren't going to have the cutting edge features of Android Studio, but Intellij works absolutely fine for Android development

Comment: @Rarw please create a new one and let us know, because i have a lag also in big projects ( i have imac late 2012)

Comment: @MounirElfassi I just made a new project to test. I get the same lag in typing with android studio as if I use the old imported project so that's not the issue

Comment: @cricket_007 imported the same project into intelij and it runs the same. Does this have something to do with the fact that it was imported from eclipse? I guess I could go back because eclipse ran smooth but would rather not

Comment: Hmm. Is it a very large app? The primary reason the IDE slows down is indexing all the files

Comment: @cricket_007 lots of visual assets so the size of the project is large; about 400 or so files total (java and xml). Ran fine in eclipse though. And there's no indication its short on memory; monitor on the bottom right doesn't come close to using max size.

Comment: @cricket_007 turned of all autocomplete, tried putting it in power save mode, turned off inspection, still the same super slow response. Even put memory settings high and still same thing. Think I'll go back to eclipse for now and try a later version since there doesn't seem to be any other settings I can change to fix this. Very odd.

Comment: You may be best filing a [bug report](http://tools.android.com/filing-bugs) to Android Studio. At least you might get a more detailed reason/answer there

Comment: I ended up trying this again after uninstalling, reinstalling, and reimporting the project in question. After that it started to run better. Not sure why but it did.