# Android Studio is lagging on macbook

Tags: macos, android-studio

I have a problem. Recently i was using a windows laptop for developing via android studio. But at the new company i  got a macbook. I am new with this os

MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2017), 
proc 2.9 GHz Intel Core i7,
 memory 16 GB 2133 MHz LPDDR3, 
graphics intel HD Graphics 630 1536 MB.

To my surprise studio on mac works very slowly, it freezes for few seconds while i writing code, when i work with layout editor, it makes me mad. I have never seen such problems on windows, studio was pretty quickly and did not annoying me so much. Mac s much powerful then my windows-laptop. Have anybody faced same problems? How can i fix it? Studio version is 3.1.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I  just turned on  invalidate/restart in the Compiler preferences and it solved my problem

[This post helped](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31668342/6643946)

Comment: Not solved my problem :(

Comment: I solved with the following way: Select 

    Apple Menu --> System Preferences --> General --> Prefer tabs 

Select `never`. Then restart Android Studio.

I am using Android Studio 4.1, but we can upgrade to available version

Answer (score 2):

Android Studio might be downloading something in background or it is connected to a mobile through lightning cable.

In these case sometimes android studio freezes. It't not a very big problem.

If this is not the condition,

Go to files>settings> and click invalidate/restart button.

This should solve all your issues.

Comment: i do invalidate/restart every half an hour. Studio loads nothing. Just a few days ago i have installed same version  studio on my windows laptop. Studio works great

Comment: @DanMan Did you buy your MacBook from an official Apple Store? If not then please return it. bcoz it may not be a **real** apple product. This happens a lot now a days.

Comment: @DanMan this should be marked as correct answer since it was before your answer

Answer (score 0):

I just switch the boot JDK, the problem resolved."Help-Find Action-switch boot JDK-select the JDK(which downloaded from the official website, my installed JDK version is 1.8.0_172)".However, it will cause Android Studio some feature unusable.
Finally, I download Android Studio 3.3 beta version, the problem resolved.

Comment: Not sure why you answer a solved question, from July…