# Cannot Start Android Studio after updating VM

Tags: macos, android-studio

Firstly, i try to add speed of my android studio in my macbook m1 16gb, Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch 1, and i follow this step

[How to speed up Android Studio on a Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28784387/how-to-speed-up-android-studio-on-a-mac)

i following the first answer and update vm option with this `-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512`. After i restart my macbook, i cannot start my android studio.

After that, I try to find vmoptions file in `~/Library/preferences/AndroidStudio` but i don't see the folder in references. And then i try to uninstall and install my android studio, but the apps still not started. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my case by deleted studio.vmoptions, with this step:

1. find the studio.vmoption using `sudo find / -name studio.vmoptions`
2. the i found my that file in here `/System/Volumes/Data/Users/macbookpro/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio2021.3/studio.vmoptions`

After i delete that file, i can run my AS greatly

Comment: i did the same but it's not opening.

Comment: i think you need to make sure that your android studio has closed, then delete it again, after that maybe need to restart your macbook, and try to open AS

Comment: yes, It requires a restart. Thanks Eko.